# Cannot compile a java class which is implemented an Interface class

Tags: java, interface

I cannot compile via CMD the class that is implemented an Interface.
But It works with any Java IDE.
Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Theses are the codes.

```
//Interface (MyInterface.java)
public interface MyInterface{ 
    public int add(int a, int b); 

}


//(MyInterfaceImpl.java)
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface { 

   public int add(int a, int b){ 
     return a + b; 
   }
}
```

```
\>javac MyInterface.java
\>javac MyInterfaceImple.java
MyInterfaceImpl.java:2: cannot file symbol
symbol: class MyInterface
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{

1 error
```

Comment: @Nanne : No lies. Now I figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your interface class is physically named MyInterfaceImple.java but your code refers to it as `MyInterfaceImpl` - (without the e).

The names used in your code need to match the physical files. Also check that both classes are in your classpath.

Answer (score 3):

You have a trailing `e` here

```
javac MyInterfaceImple.java
                     ^
```

but not here

```
//(MyInterfaceImpl.java)
```

which may be a problem.

---

Also, if your interface / class reside in a package, this may be a problem. If so, please include the `package` lines and directory structure.

---

Everything works as expected my machine. Here's a demo:

```
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ cat -> MyInterface.java
    //Interface (MyInterface.java)
    public interface MyInterface{ 
        public int add(int a, int b); 

    }
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ cat -> MyInterfaceImpl.java
    //(MyInterfaceImpl.java)
    public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface { 

       public int add(int a, int b){ 
         return a + b; 
       }
    }

aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ 
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ ls
MyInterfaceImpl.java  MyInterface.java
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ javac MyInterface.java 
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp/java$ javac MyInterfaceImpl.java
```

Comment: @Mikaveli: 'e' is a mistake and sorry for that. Actually this is the case. I did a RMI and RPC app for one of my assignment and it worked well. After about 2 months later(yesterday) I ran it again for another purpose. RMI did not work. After I figured out the error arises due to the interface. I just create a demo and ran it. error was still there. But with an IDE (Netbeanse or sth) again it workd. In linux it works well. the original program has a directory structure and it runs using a .bat or .sh. That is why I put a sample code here.

Comment: @sura. No worries. If you accept some of the answers to old questions, most people won't downvote you.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Truly. Can you tell me how to accept those, If I want

Comment: @Mikaveli  Tell me how to accept those If there are helpful replies?

Comment: @Mikavel: I found It. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sura2k, If you have a directory structure, and packages you should include these in the problem description.